# Multiple and recursive file renaming in bash

Tags: bash, rename

In `Linux` I have a folder with the following structure:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── 00000400000000030bfd.dat
│   ├── 10000400000000030bfd.dat
│   ├── 20000400000000030bfd.dat
│   ├── etc....
├── b
│   ├── 00000401000000030bfd.dat
│   ├── 10000401000000030bfd.dat
│   ├── 20000401000000030bfd.dat
│   ├── etc....
├── c
│   ├── 00000402000000030bfd.dat
│   ├── 10000402000000030bfd.dat
│   ├── 20000402000000030bfd.dat
│   ├── etc....
├── d
│   ├── etc....
├── e
│   ├── etc....
├── f
```

And so on until the `"p"` folder. I want to rename every `.dat` file in every directory to `.html` file with a `bash` script. How i can do it?

Comment: What did you try for yourself? How did you fail?

Comment: I tried with `for i in 'ls -lR' do mv $i $i.html; done` and others combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop.

```
for file in {a..p}/*.dat ; do
    mv "$file" "${file%.dat}.html"
done
```

`${file%.dat}` removes `.dat` from the end of the value of the `$file`.

Comment: Single loop over `for file in [a-p]/*.dat`? Or even `{a..p}/*.dat` to avoid locale problems.

Comment: Sorry, just saw that you actually mention that. I think for loops are exempt of command line length maximum: `touch {000001..1000000}` gives "Argument list too long"; `for f in {000001..1000000}; do touch $f; done` works fine.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: OK, updated. It seems the distinction is in fact builtin commands and keywords against external commands.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses all traditional commands:

```
find log -name "*.dat" | 
  sed 's/.log$//;s/mv &.dat &.html/' |
  bash
```

Essentially, the `find` creates the target name list, the `sed` makes the names generic and then generates a `mv` command that does the rename and then pipes the results to `bash` for execution.

The `bash` command can be omitted to merely get a list of the mv commands for eyeball testing.  You can also add a `-x` to the `bash` command to get a log of each `mv` command executed.